# automate mapping types in Auto Mapper by inheriting from a custom interface in Asp.net Core 1

Tags: c#, automapper, structuremap, asp.net-core-1.0

I want to automate the mapping process by getting instances that inherit from IMapFrom interface like flowing:

```
        var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes();
        var maps = (
                from type in types
                from instance in type.GetInterfaces()
                where
                    instance.IsGenericType &&
                    instance.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMapFrom<>) &&
                    !type.IsAbstract &&
                    !type.IsInterface
                select new
                {
                    Source = instance.GetGenericArguments()[0],
                    Destination = type
                }
            ).ToArray();

        foreach (var map in maps)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap(map.Source, map.Destination);
        }
```

but there is no 
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes()
in .net core 1.
so what is the solution?

PS: I use structure map as DI container and  I tried to use it like this:

```
        Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.AssembliesAndExecutablesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(
                assembly => assembly.FullName.StartsWith("MyAssemblyName")
                );
            scan.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IMapFrom<>));
            scan.AddAllTypesOf<IHaveCustomMappings>();
        });
```

but I cannot find a way to inject IEnamarable of  IMapFrom<> interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that there is no GetExecutingAssembly() in .net Core.

What you now have to do is reference a particular type and get the assembly of that type. For example :

```
typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetExportedTypes();
```

In your case instead of using the Startup class you will want to reference a type that is in the same assembly as your mapping objects.